# Enviando post para ActionResult via knockout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockoutjs

Fala pessoal, seguinte: Estou tentando enviar um `post` usando o `ko`, para um método `ActionResult` do meu *controller* ao invés de um `JsonResult` como de costume. Ao debugar o projeto ele entra no `ActionResult` mas não abre a *View* na qual estou requisitando. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Meu ko:

```
self.Edita = function (usuario) {
self.usuario(usuario);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditarUsuario", "Administracao")',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: ko.toJSON(usuario),
    success: {}
});
```

};

Meu controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditarUsuario(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

A minha ideia na verdade é apenas pegar os dados da *model* que vêm como parâmetro para trabalhar com a mesma na *view* `EditarUsuario` não preciso retornar nada. Tem como fazer isso com o `JsonResult`?

Comment: Você quer que o Ajax faça a transição da tela também?

Comment: Não não... Enviado para o ActionResult não necessito retornar nada via Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, isso não vai funcionar. Um `ActionResult` mexe diretamente na requisição da página. Fazendo a requisição por Ajax, o que será retornado será uma *View*, que será encapsulada pelo Ajax.

Para este caso, é melhor usar um formulário normal mesmo, ou ainda enviar para o Ajax um `JsonResult` e então redirecionar a página:

```
self.Edita = function (usuario) {
self.usuario(usuario);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditarUsuario", "Administracao")',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: ko.toJSON(usuario),
    success: function (result) {
        window.location = '/Controller/MinhaAction';
    }
});
```

Comment: Fiz o que vc disse Cigano... Funcionou. Vlws